# PFquery table view control show detail

Tags: iphone, parse-platform

I'm looking for a way to transport data entered into the database from a view to another. I have a table view controller with university exams inserted every examination must show your card, calling its data from the data browser to Parse the current user through the

```
- (void) prepareForSegue: (uistoryboardSegue)
```

Comment: Please explain what you have tried so far and explain what it did and what it did not do as you wanted; including showing any code you have tried. SO is about the question, so the personal remarks are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Then I try to explain as best as possible ...

I downloaded from the project parse.com PFQueryTableViewController.
I entered all the data perfectly recall the Databrowser ...
My cells are thus created:

```
#import "TableViewParse.h"
#import "CustomNav.h"
#import "ListaInAttesa.h"

@implementation TableViewParse
@synthesize TableViewInAttesa;



- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];




        // Custom the table

        // The className to query on
        self.parseClassName = @"miaclasse";

        // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
        self.textKey = @"titolomio";


        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        self.paginationEnabled = YES;

        // The number of objects to show per page
        self.objectsPerPage = 5;

     [CustomNav NavBar];

    return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];



    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.

    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - Parse

- (void)objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error {
    [super objectsDidLoad:error];

    // This method is called every time objects are loaded from Parse via the PFQuery
}

- (void)objectsWillLoad {
    [super objectsWillLoad];

    // This method is called before a PFQuery is fired to get more objects
}


// Override to customize what kind of query to perform on the class. The default is to query for
// all objects ordered by createdAt descending.
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
        [query whereKey: @"user" equalTo: [PFUser currentUser]];

    // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
    // and then subsequently do a query against the network.
    if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    }
    [query orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];

    return query;
}




// Override to customize the look of a cell representing an object. The default is to display
// a UITableViewCellStyleDefault style cell with the label being the first key in the object.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell
    cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"titolomio"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Questo esame è previsto per il : %@", [object objectForKey:@"datamia"]];

    return cell;
}


/*
 // Override if you need to change the ordering of objects in the table.
 - (PFObject *)objectAtIndex:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 return [objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 }
 */


// Override to customize the look of the cell that allows the user to load the next page of objects.
// The default implementation is a UITableViewCellStyleDefault cell with simple labels.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForNextPageAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NextPage";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Visualizza ancora ....";

    return cell;
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source


// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}



// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [object deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            [self loadObjects];
        }];
    }
}



// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}



// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}




- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Esamiinattesa"])
    {
       // NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
       // ListaInAttesa *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
       // destViewController.title = [self.postController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}


#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   // [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Esamiinattesa" sender:indexPath];

}

@end
```

Now I need that when the user clicks on a current exam placed in the cell Tableview is sent to a specific viewcontroller where inside are called the results of the examination the time the user selected current ...

I know that it is "prepareForSegue" but I can not figure out where I'm wrong, maybe I'm wrong just the procedure to obtain the required result.

P.S.I realized just now that I connected with the user's findanzato because I changed my pc and I kept doing the same id logout ... Sorry ... We are working on this project in two App